# jQuery diable multiselect drop-down option

Tags: html, jquery

I got a multi-select drop-down ordered as a  like this:

```
   <ul>
    <li title="Africa" aria-selected="false">Africa</li>
    <li title="Egypt" aria-selected="false">Egypt</li>
    <li title="Angola" aria-selected="false">Angola</li>
    <li title="Benin" aria-selected="false">Benin</li>
    <li title="Asia" aria-selected="false">Asia</li>
    <li title="Taiwan" aria-selected="false">Taiwan</li>
    <li title="India" aria-selected="false">India</li>
    <li title="Thailand" aria-selected="false">Thailand</li>
    <li title="Europe" aria-selected="false">Europe</li>
    <li title="Denmark" aria-selected="false">Denmark</li>
    <li title="Italy" aria-selected="false">Italy</li>
    <li title="Spain" aria-selected="false">Spain</li>
    </ul>
```

**What I am aiming for is to disable the continents (Africa, Asia, Europe) so that they are not selectable.**

I have figured that if I completely remove the `aria-selected="false"` attribute + value and add `aria-disabled="true"` for the continents the become un-selectable.

I thought this was the way to do it for a single continent:
(*Preferably there should be a more dynamic way so I don't have to repeat this for each continent*)

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    $("ul li[title='Africa']").removeAttr("aria-selected");
    $("ul li[title='Africa']").attr("aria-disabled","true");

});
```

..but nothing happens. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: This isn't the standard HTML code for a select, so you must have some other script that changes this into a select. What are you using to do this? If you can show us the HTML that is generated instead of the source ul, we might be able to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead,

I created a array for hidden items

```
var titles= ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe"];
```

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    var titles= ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe"];
    
    for(var i=0;i<=titles.length;i++){
      $("ul li[title="+titles[i]+"]").removeAttr("aria-selected");
      $("ul li[title="+titles[i]+"]").attr("aria-disabled","true");
    }
});
```

```css
li[aria-disabled="true"]{
  color:#888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li title="Africa" aria-selected="false">Africa</li>
    <li title="Egypt" aria-selected="false">Egypt</li>
    <li title="Angola" aria-selected="false">Angola</li>
    <li title="Benin" aria-selected="false">Benin</li>
    <li title="Asia" aria-selected="false">Asia</li>
    <li title="Taiwan" aria-selected="false">Taiwan</li>
    <li title="India" aria-selected="false">India</li>
    <li title="Thailand" aria-selected="false">Thailand</li>
    <li title="Europe" aria-selected="false">Europe</li>
    <li title="Denmark" aria-selected="false">Denmark</li>
    <li title="Italy" aria-selected="false">Italy</li>
    <li title="Spain" aria-selected="false">Spain</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you explain how you got the jQuery they posted in the question to work? It looks identical except for the dynamic title, and they said that didn't disable the dropdown options in their project, so I'm curious myself how adding a dynamic title fixed that problem?